# How do I pass arguments to bash with quotation marks

Tags: bash, command-line-arguments, quotation-marks

I have a script which calls a C++ application with command line switches set. What I would like to do is pass the app switches as parameters to the script.

```bash
    options=$1
    ...
    ./app $options
```

The problem occurs when I try to pass an parameter like:

```bash
    ./script '-a -C "9.626 0.262 8.266"'
```

The value of the -C switch is just 9.626 instead of the whole string. Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use an array.

```
options=( -a -C "9.626 0.262 8.266" )
./script "${options[@]}"
```

Inside `script`, `$1` is `-a`, `$2` is `-C`, and `$3` is `9.626 0.262 8.266`. (Notice the quotes are not part of `$3`; they are only used to protect the whitespace while setting the arguments to `script`. Presumably, you intend to pass all three arguments to some other command, and you would do so with

```
other_command "$1" "$2" "$3"
```

or more generally, to accommodate an arbitrary number of arguments

```
other_command "$@"
```